# I am trying to use regular expression for extracting the Filename filed in Splunk,I have attached the same text

Tags: regex, splunk, splunk-query

ID=6913&Filename=**C%3A%5CUsers%5CTHanse04%5CAppData%5CRoaming%5CDocumentum%5CViewed%5C181019_ERS_321_102_500857.pdf**&Download=65536&DownloadSize=79243 HTTP/1.1" 200 3 "-" "Java/1.8.0_192"

I need to extract and after extract i need Thanse04 from it
Filename=C%3A%5CUsers%5C**THanse04**%5CAppData%5CRoaming%5CDocumentum%5CViewed%5C181019_ERS_321_102_500857.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(?:Filename=)(.*)(.pdf)(?:&)

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/aZfgvt/1)

Explanation: (?:) is a matching but not capturing group. Here it matches 'Filename= but does not capture it. The regex keeps on capturing until it captures .pdf and then makes sure that the next character after that is & which it also matches but does not capture.

Comment: @Anshuman your welcome. Please accept the answer. That way others will not try to answer an answered question. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Try `Filename=%3A%5CUsers%5C(?<user>[^%]+)`.